# Find Other C flags in Xcode 7

Tags: xcode, opencl, openmp

I try to install openMP(because  file not found) in my Xcode in order to run OpenMP.
I followed this instruction to do, but I couldn't find where the Other C Flags is. Please help me find the place. Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJvQT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNCIG.png)

Answer (score 1):

They're under Apple LLVM 7.1 - Custom Compiler Flags.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to click on All instead of Basic in settings